# Animacion boton leer mas o leer menos

Tags: javascript, html, css3, animación

estaba practicando utilizar el boton leer mas o leer menos para mostrar o no un texto, lo pude hacer mi problema es que no se como hacer una animacion, yo quiero que al mostrar el parrafo, el cambio no sea tran brusco,que tarde unos 3 segundos por lo menos. Asi sea para mostrarlo y tambien para ocultarlo.
¿Alguna idea? Mil gracias dejo mi codigo

```js
const parrafo = document.querySelector(".parrafo");
const boton = document.querySelector(".boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  parrafo.classList.toggle("parrafo-visible")

  if (parrafo.classList.contains("parrafo-visible")) {

    boton.innerHTML = "Leer menos";
  } else {
    boton.innerHTML = "Leer más";
  }

})
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1 class="titulo">
    Hola perros
  </h1>
  <p class="parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat dicta rem fugiat numquam at maxime expedita voluptate fugit, culpa soluta, voluptatibus facere quo autem laudantium corporis molestiae? Voluptatem, temporibus pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reprehenderit expedita explicabo libero officia impedit nisi odio. Fuga velit rerum sit nisi corrupti earum temporibus, officia, eveniet voluptas aperiam sint. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Nam delectus, facilis saepe placeat mollitia minima repudiandae dignissimos. Voluptatem doloremque deserunt suscipit, recusandae voluptas quia. At molestias laborum neque quos fugiat! </p>
  <button class="boton">Leer mas</button>
</div>
```

Css3:

```
.contenedor{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    
}
.titulo{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.parrafo{
  display:none;
  
 
}

.parrafo-visible{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  
}

.boton{
       display: block;
       margin: auto;
       font-size: 20px;
       border-radius: 30px;
       padding: 10px 20px;
       cursor: pointer;
       border: none;   
}
```

Comment: puedes hacerlo con css y la propiedad transition.

Comment: No veo que tu botón oculte o muestre el contenido del texto. Cómo lo estás implementando actualmente? Agrega el código CSS adicional, tus clases personalizadas

Comment: Jheyman ahi pude poner mi codigo css, intente usar la prop transition pero no lo logro.

Comment: Bryro podrias ser mas especifico, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edité la respuesta debido a que comentaste que no deseas **jQuery**, entonces prueba así:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".boton");
const text = document.querySelector(".leer-mas");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    text.classList.toggle("leer-mas_open");
    text.classList.contains("leer-mas_open") ? btn.innerHTML = "Leer Menos" : btn.innerHTML = "Leer Mas";
});
```

```css
    .leer-mas {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .leer-mas_open {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        max-height: 500px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 40rem; /*PUEDES CAMBIAR PARA MODIFICAR EL ANCHO DEL DIV PADRE*/
        color: #000;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .contenedor {
        padding: 0.25rem;
    }

    .titulo {
        font-size: 1.7em;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .boton {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        background-color: grey;
        padding: 0.6rem 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1em;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .boton:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: grey;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2 rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        transform: translateY(-3px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contenedor">
        <h1 class="titulo"> Hola perros</h1>
        <p id="parrafo">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            <span class="leer-mas">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat dicta rem fugiat numquam at maxime expedita voluptate fugit, culpa soluta, voluptatibus facere quo autem laudantium corporis molestiae? Voluptatem, temporibus pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci reprehenderit expedita explicabo libero officia impedit nisi odio. Fuga velit rerum sit nisi corrupti earum temporibus, officia, eveniet voluptas aperiam sint. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Nam delectus, facilis saepe placeat mollitia minima repudiandae dignissimos. Voluptatem doloremque deserunt suscipit, recusandae voluptas quia. At molestias laborum neque quos fugiat!
            </span>
        </p>
        <p class="boton">Read More</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Evil agradezco tu respuesta pero no podria ser posible lograr lo mismo sin usar jquery? estoy intentando usar transition en css y no lo logro.  gracias igual

Comment: Edité la respuesta, ojalá te sirva. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio. Saludos

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como correcta, saludos